# Can we Hold DataModel(Poco) in Session?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

My `SessionContext` class is given below,I want to set User property as SiteUserDomainModel(it is a POCO model). But I am thinking, if is it a good idea? Can I replace this to something like SiteUserSessionModel(it will be mapped from SiteUserDomainModel)?

Actually, my question is; in a session, can we hold Domain(POCO) classes?

```
public static class SessionContext
{
   public static SiteUserDomainModel User
   {
      get
      {
         var user = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] as SiteUserDomainModel;
         return user;
                    }
      set
      {
         HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do it? Yes, as long as they are [Serializable].

Is it a good idea? No, do your best to avoid it.